# PHP Array to jQuery - gmaps.js not creating marker

Tags: php, jquery, gmaps.js

I'm trying to use a PHP Array to get long and lat values from a database, and put these onto a map using gmaps.js.

So far, I have created the array in PHP, and echoed this onto my page to confirm the correct values are being displayed.

```
$data = array();
$data['latitude'] = array($lat);
$data['longitude'] = array($lng);
echo json_encode($data);
```

So $data is the array, with the values I want inside.

I then want to use jQuery to get the data from json encode, put these into the map marker locations and display the markers like so:

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "phppage.php",
        dataType: "JSON",
        success: function(data) {
            $.each(data, function(key, value) {
                poi_marker = {
                     marker: {
                        lat: data.latitude,
                        lng: data.longitude,
                        }
                      } 
                }
                poi_markers.push(poi_marker);
            });

            map.addMarkers(poi_markers);
        }
    });
```

I get no errors in my console (using firefox and firebug), the map displays but no markers are shown.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that you're code is actually doing what you think that it is doing. See [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cgt7ejvj/) for what is actually happening with your loop.

If you store the array differently on the PHP side, it'll be easier to loop through multiple markers in JS. Also, I don't think `gmaps.js` needs that extra 'marker' key in the object.

**New PHP**

```
$data = array();
$data[] = array(
  'latitude' => $lat
  ,'longitude' => $long
);
echo json_encode($data);
```

**New JS**

```
var poi_markers = []; // make sure you declare this before using it. if you already declare it somewhere else, don't use this line
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "phppage.php",
    dataType: "JSON",
    success: function(data) {
        $.each(data, function(key, value) {
            var poi_marker = {
                lat: value.latitude,
                lng: value.longitude
            }
            poi_markers.push(poi_marker);
        });

        map.addMarkers(poi_markers);
    }
});
```

You might be having trouble because you specify `dataType: "JSON"` but (atleast in the code you posted) you don't change the header on the php side. You may need to add this line to the top of `phppage.php`

```
header("Content-Type: application/json", true);
```

[Where I learned everything I know about gmaps.js](https://hpneo.github.io/gmaps/examples/json.html)

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that the data retrieved successfully as needed

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "phppage.php",
    dataType: "JSON",
    success: function(data) {
        $.each(data, function(key, value) {
            map.addMarker{
                lat: data.latitude,
                lng: data.longitude
            }
        }  
    }     
});
```

[Check This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21119939/gmaps-js-multiple-markers-with-dynamic-infowindow-content)

Comment: I checked the link, however it didn't help. When I add the marker hard coded, like [so](https://jsfiddle.net/rh3jgjq4/) it works fine. However I cannot seem to use JSON encode to pass the data

Comment: I can however echo the values via PHP. I know this isn't the best practice, however how would I go about running through a PHP array to echo the values?

Comment: you could use JSON.parse(data); to use the array easly

Comment: could you please make a snippet with your original code please